# $(declare -p) keeps adding backslashes

Tags: linux, bash, variable, subshell

From `help declare`:

```
-p        display the attributes and value of each NAME
```

Just running `declare -p` works as expected. So does running it in a subshell with `(declare -p)`.

However, when using `echo "$(declare -p)"`, i.e. executing the command in a subshell, catching `stdout` and echoing that to `stdout` again, I noticed something weird happening: With each call, the output of `declare -p` gets longer and additional backslashes appear. The execution also takes increasingly longer.

Output of first run of `echo "$(declare -p)"`:

```
...
declare -x SHELL="/bin/bash"
...
```

Second run:

```
...
declare -x SHELL="/bin/bash"
...
declare -x SHELL=\"/bin/bash\"
...
```

Third run:

```
...
declare -x SHELL="/bin/bash"
...
declare -x SHELL=\"/bin/bash\"
...
declare -x SHELL=\\\"/bin/bash\\\"
...
```

What's going on here?

Comment: As you're doing this, take note of the first line starting with `declare -- _="` -- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005f

Comment: @glennjackman Ohhh so I'm simply seeing the very long content of the `_` variable! I would've never thought of that. Thank you very much for your help :)